# How to replicate Node's Crypto.createHmac( 'sha256', buffer) in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

How to get to "feature parity" between Node's `Crypto.createHmac( 'sha256', buffer)` and `CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(..., secret)`?

I have a 3rd party code that does what you can see here as the method `node1`. I would need to achieve the same result in the browser. Seemingly, the difference is in the that the `secret` is base64 decoded on the node side. But I still can't get the same output.

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')
const Crypto = require('crypto')

const message = "Message"
const secret = "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="

function node1() {
  return Crypto.createHmac("sha256", Buffer.from(secret, 'base64'))
      .update(message, "utf8")
      .digest("base64");
}

function node2() {
  return Crypto.createHmac("sha256", Buffer.from(secret, 'base64').toString('base64'))
      .update(message, "utf8")
      .digest("base64");
}

function browser() {
  const crypted = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, secret)
  return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(crypted)
}

console.log('node1', node1())
console.log('node2', node2())
console.log('browser-like', browser())

// node1 agitai8frSJpJuXwd4HMJC/t2tluUJPMZy8CeYsEHTE=
// node2 fxJQFWs5W3A4otaAlnlV0kh4yfQPb4Y1ChSVZsUAAXA=
// browser-like fxJQFWs5W3A4otaAlnlV0kh4yfQPb4Y1ChSVZsUAAXA=
```

So, I can reproduce a naive browser-like behaviour in node. This gave me the idea to use `atob` in the browser, to reproduce node's behaviour. The following `sign` method is my best guess on the browser side.

```
function sign(message) {
  const crypted = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, atob(secret));
  return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(crypted)
}

function signNotDecoded(message) {
  const crypted = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, secret);
  return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(crypted)
}

console.log('browser', sign('Message'))
console.log('browser-like', signNotDecoded('Message'))

// browser dnVm5jBgIBNV6pFd4J9BJTjx3BFsm7K32SCcEQX7RHA= 
// browser-like fxJQFWs5W3A4otaAlnlV0kh4yfQPb4Y1ChSVZsUAAXA=
```

So, running `signDecoded()` in the browser, and running `browser()` in node gives the same output. Running both `node2()` and `browser()` in node again provide the same output, but still `sign()` differs from `node1()`.

Based on the above, I'm quite sure that the problem is with my usage of atob, but what do I miss there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
atob(secret)
```

To

```
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(secret)
```

Because if you pass a raw string as key to the function it will be re-parsed as UTF-8.